# Where is the missing image reference?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to debug a WordPress site and have been scouring through the custom CSS to find out why the site keep loading a background [image](https://lonelyplanetwp.imgix.net/2014/10/8642451160_b0660b13a3_o.jpg) that has since been deleted. This is appearing on every page as a 404 error.

Does anyone know how to reverse engineer this situation to isolate where it might be coming from?

```
<meta name="generator" content="Powered by Visual Composer - drag and drop page builder for WordPress."/>
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/vc_lte_ie9.min.css" media="screen"><![endif]--><!--[if IE  8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/vc-ie8.min.css" media="screen"><![endif]--><style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-image: url("https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/8642451160_b0660b13a3_o.jpg"); background-position: left top; background-size: auto; background-repeat: repeat; background-attachment: scroll; }
</style>
<style>.fb_iframe_widget_lift {width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important;}</style><style></style>
```

Comment: Can you provide a URL to your site please? Are you running any caching plugins? What Host?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a search for `8642451160_b0660b13a3_o.jpg` over the theme files and plugin files using `grep` or any similar utility to search for text in multiple text files.

If this doesn’t help, perform a search for `8642451160_b0660b13a3_o.jpg` in the whole database using phpMyAdmin or similar tool. By looking at which database tables and records it was found it, you can usually track the plugin or the theme file it’s set in.

WordPress is very flexible, and allows to append a style to the header from practically any place in the code (for example, by using the [`wp_head` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head#Examples) in **almost any PHP file**). So, the problematic code can be virtually anywhere! Doing a search for the filename in the files and in the database can usually help to track where the problem comes from.